# Disable auto topic creation when calling GetMetadata

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am using [confluent golang](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go) for my Kafka client. I use `AdminClient` to create/delete/get topics in kafka cluster. Here is my code to initialize `AdminClient`

```
adminClient, err := kafka.NewAdminClient(&kafka.ConfigMap{
    "bootstrap.servers": 127.0.0.1:9092,
})
```

After that, I use this class to create and get all topics in kafka cluster. Here is the code for creating a topic:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
defer cancel()

results, err := adminClient.CreateTopics(
    ctx,
    []kafka.TopicSpecification{{
        Topic:             topic,
        NumPartitions:     numPartitions,
        ReplicationFactor: replicationFactor}},
    kafka.SetAdminOperationTimeout(TimeOut),
)
```

After that, I get again topic information:

```
result, err := adminClient.GetMetadata(&topic, false, 1000)
```

The problem is: If I get a topic that not existed before, kafka will automatically create that topic. This is a behavior that I don't want. Please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable automatic creation of topics, you should update your broker configurations to have `auto.create.topics.enable` as `false`. Take a look at [the docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) or this [page](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_kafka-component-guide/content/kafka-broker-settings.html)

Comment: thanks. I know this option before. I just think it means if we post a message into non-exist topic, it will automatically create topic. I don't know that only check info of topic also creates automatically topic. I think this behavior is annoy. :D